# Can not leave comments

Tags: support

Who can tell me why I am cut off from leaving comments? Spending the time to compose a comment then nothing showing up is rather irritating.

Comment: That usually means some corrupted javascript. Try forcibly reloading pages and/or clearing your caches.

Comment: Cleared cache and still can not leave comments - Firefox on a Mac. I'll switch to a Debian box and try.

Comment: @dmckee  That works here, but not in PhysicsSE!

Answer (score 2):

Problem "solved". Disable new "Mathjax Buttons" I loaded from a description on the right of the questions page. Fixes two different commenting problems here and on ElectronicsSE plus fixes problem with the Stackexchange pull-down menu to go to other SE pages.

Now to find how to reach the Mathjax Buttons author.....

Comment: That's easy, you just ping @Manishearth. Moderators receive pings throughout the site, I believe. Ideally, you should comment on [the original MathJax buttons thread](http://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons), though.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I don't know about mods being always-pingable. They can ping anyone, but it is [recommended to use flags for reaching them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126988/an-moderators-ping). That said, this is not really a flag issue. Manishearth is usually in chat, and if he's been there in the last 2 days, you can ping him there.